# Is it possible to express 0,999... (repeating decimal) in MS Excel? How?

Tags: excel, math

Repeating decimals as `0,333...` and `0,666...` are respectively expressed by `=1/3` and `=2/3`, but how is it possible to express `0,999...` in MS Excel (using a similar aproach or not)?

**EDIT**

For now I decided to determine `=1-(10^-20)` as my solution.

Comment: Or in Google Spreadsheet, as you want.

Comment: If you're fine with `0,333...=1/3` and `0,666...=2/3`, I don't see why you don't want `0,999...=1` and instead want `1-(10^-20)`.

Comment: Now it's complex to explain it here, but basically I wanted to use `0.999`... in a `=log(n)` function. Actually, this function is inside another bigger function. Well, `=log(1)` is zero, and as this result is used later as a divisor, it would generates an error.

Comment: So I wondered if I could use a number very close to 1, as `=log(0.999999999)` which generates `-0.0000000004`, and no error. Then I asked myself if I could use a repeating decimal, just to avoid this error, but I was wrong (:

Comment: Mathematically `1 = 0,999...` is acceptable, and that's the reason why there is no way to express `0,999...` in MS Excel or Google sheets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a fundamental feature of real arithmetic that

```
1 == 0.99999999999...
```

so I suggest you type `1` into a cell.

Comment: I found [this concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...) and I decided to determine `=1-(10^-5)` for my solution.

Answer (score -1):

Store numerator and denominator separately in two cells

Comment: yes, and what should be the numerator and what should be the denominator?

Comment: it depends on what numbers you have and how do you get them